# jqGrid 3.7.2 does it contain the hoverrows feature?

Tags: jqgrid, tooltip

Although I have set hoverrows: false, a tooltip is being displayed when the mouse hovers over any grid cell in version 3.7.2.

I found this link from December 2009:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/supress-jqgrid-onmouseoverhover-code

which mentions the feature being available "in the final release".  Version 3.7.2 dates from July 2010, so I assumed it incorporated the hoverrows feature mentioned last year.  Is it perhaps not included yet? Or maybe I am setting the property at the wrong time? I am setting this property after defining the *colModel* but before the grid is populated with data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, `hoverrows` only disables the effect of highlighting an entire grid row when the mouse hovers over that row. Despite Tony's comments on that forum thread, I have not seen this option disable tooltips in grids with this option set.

Comment: Thanks for the corroboration, Justin. I'll use the code Tony posts to remove the title from every cell.